# drawRect causes slow scrolling even though it is not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, drawrect

In my app I have a scrollView with about 20 subviews in it. Each of these subviews has a drawRect method that at the moment looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawRect called");
}
```

When the subviews are added, drawRect is called, however when I scroll it is very slow even though drawRect is not called again.

If I remove the implementation for drawRect, then scrolling is completely normal. Even if I can't get rid of the slow scrolling, is there an alternative to drawRect which I could use instead?

Comment: Your sub views are being added during scrolling? Calling NSLog during scrolling will definitely cause slower scrolling. Also, in general avoid allocating things while scrolling if you are performance tuning.

Comment: @nielsbot But he isn't allocating anything in his code; he is just logging text.

Comment: Have you set your subviews opaque?

Comment: @qegal noted.. although i was referring to the possibility he is allocating subviews to place in his scroll view on scroll, and also just as general advice.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling drawRect if it is only logging that it was called? If that is it's only purpose for you, then just don't call it. In fact, I believe when you first create a class that inherits from UIView that has the drawRect method in it, it is commented out and above the commented out drawRect method, it says something along the lines of "Do not call this method if it does not do any drawing on screen as it takes up a significant amount of memory". Basically, don't call it in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Exact warning text is: "Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing. An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation."

Comment: Yep. Did you fix it by not using drawRect?

Comment: I only have an empty implementation of drawRect at the moment because I wanted to make sure it wasn't something I was doing wrong within the drawRect method that was causing the slow down. Thats the only reason why I'm just logging the call. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: So basically you want either an alternative to drawRect or a way to boost the performance of drawRect as to not cause a slow down, right?

Comment: Maybe you could have a NSMutableArray full of UIView objects and assign one UIView object to each scrollView item. Then you can create a CGContextRef and use Core Graphics to draw instead. I'm not very confident in my knowledge of Core Graphics, so I can't go around telling you how to implement this, but its an idea.

Comment: "If I remove the implementation for drawRect, then scrolling is completely normal." Do you need to use drawRect or not? If so, implement it as you want (instead of empty), then optimize when ready, otherwise, just remove it.

Comment: The drawRect method is already causing considerable slowdown even with an empty implementation, which is why I'm wondering if there is a better way of drawing in a UIView. If scrolling is already slow even with an empty implementation, then I don't want to use it for drawing. I only have the drawRect method empty at the moment to show that it wasn't the code that was being executed inside drawRect that was causing slow scrolling but just the drawRect method itself.

Comment: @CiaranLawlor I have the same issue. Did you find any solutions for using it?

Comment: @CiaranLawlor The same for me. Any ideas how to solve/workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning pre-drawn CGImages to the contents of each custom view's CALayer, before the view first appears.   This may be faster than using a drawRect to customize a view's appearance.